# Dominant morphism $P^1\to P^1$ which is not an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $P^1$ be over an algebraically closed base field.

My aim is to find a dominant morphism $P^1\to P^1$ which is not an isomorphism. I am disturbed by this since I am convinced it is not possible.

First, such a morphism $\phi$ must in fact be surjective. I also know that $\phi^*$ on the function fields would be injective. I believe that in fact $\phi^*$ is also necessarily surjective, although I cannot prove this. But then this would mean that $\phi^*$ is given by a linear polynomial, so $\phi$ would be an isomorphism. So if I am right, I simply need to show that $\phi^*$ is surjective, but if I am wrong, then there would be counterexample exploiting exactly this potential failure of $\phi^*$ is to be surjective.

I also have a similar, potentially related result in my text, which states that for any smooth variety of dimension $1$ and a dominant morphism $\phi:P^1\to X$, we must have that $X$ is isomorphic to $P^1$. The proof of this uses Luroth's theorem in a critical way, but I'm not sure how exactly to connect this to the problem at hand.

Comment: Consider the case of $\mathbb R P^1$ in smooth manifold land. This is just the circle $S^1$. Do you know a surjective map $S^1 \to S^1$ that is not an isomorphism? Can you imitate this on $\mathbb P^1$?

Comment: @TabesBridges Ah I see, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First, such a morphism $\phi$ must in fact be surjective. I also know that $\phi^*$ on the function fields would be injective. I believe that in fact $\phi^*$ is also necessarily surjective, although I cannot prove this.

This is false. A simple counterexample is the map $k(x) \xrightarrow{x \mapsto x^2} k(x)$, which exhibits $k(x)$ as a subfield of itself of index $2$ (namely $k(x^2)$). This corresponds to a map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $2$ given in homogeneous coordinates by $(X : Y) \mapsto (X^2 : Y^2)$.

More generally dominant maps $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ over a field $k$ correspond naturally to homomorphisms $k(x) \xrightarrow{f} k(x)$ (necessarily injective) over $k$, which in turn correspond to nonzero rational functions $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \in k(x)$ (the image of $x$ under the map $f$). This map is an isomorphism iff $f$ is a Mobius transformation $f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d}, ad - bc \neq 0$.